# Is there a better way to write this call to numerous NSUserDefault BOOLS?

Tags: ios, boolean, nsuserdefaults

I am tying to optimise my code and improve my programming. I am looking at this statement which get updated constantly.

Is there a better way to right the calls to numerous `BOOLS`? Is it possible to include them in a `FOR` statement?

```
baseballHat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:
 @"baseballHat"];

 asianHat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"asianHat"];

    cowboyHat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"cowboyHat"];

    topHat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"topHat"];

    partyHat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"partyHat"];

    sumbreroHat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"sumbreroHat"];

     wizardHat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"wizardHat"];

     beretHat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"beretHat"];

    pirateHat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"pirateHat"];

     vikingHelmet = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"vikingHelmet"];


     if(baseballHat == YES){

         _baseballWearBut.visible = YES;
        _baseballHatOwned.visible = YES;

    }
      if(topHat == YES){

         //Continue with if statements
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"baseball", @"asian", @"cowboy", @"top"]; //and the other ones
for (NSString *prefixKey in array) 
{
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Hat", prefixKey];
    BOOL boolValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:key];
    [self setValue:@(boolValue) forKey:key]; 
}
```

I don't recommend it, I don't like calling variable by "their name" (using `valueForKey:`).

Another way could be to use a `NSDictionary` or an `NSArray`, but then, you'll need to encapsulate your `BOOL` into object (`NSNumber` for example), and may add another level.
You may have to reconsider your architecture app.
Is the `Hat` thing just a `BOOL` ? Does it has more info? Could it be just a var into a different object (like, creating a Class with a var `hat`)?
Can you have various of this hatvalues to `TRUE`? If not, maybe using a `enumdef` could be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
// *** Following is few snippets ***

// *** Create a Dictionary with various states ***
NSMutableDictionary *dictStates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictStates setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"asianHat"];
[dictStates setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"cowboyHat"];
[dictStates setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"topHat"];

// *** Save them to UserDefaults ***
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dictStates forKey:@"MyStates"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// *** Again Access all the various states stored in UserDefaults ***
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyStates"];

// *** Iterate through all the Objects ***
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key , obj);
}];

// *** Modify Existing value and store again to UserDefaults ***
// *** Create Mutable Copy of Dictionary ***
NSMutableDictionary *dictModified = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyStates"] mutableCopy];
// *** modify value ***
[dictModified setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"topHat"];
// *** Save them to UserDefaults ***
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dictModified forKey:@"MyStates"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```